# make `find` return with a non-zero exit code if error occured

Tags: bash, shell-script, find

Why am I seeing the following:

```
$ find  -not -exec bash -c 'foo' \; -quit
bash: foo: command not found
$ echo $?
0
```

This is a reduced version of the actual script I am using which I post at the end of the question (if you really want to know).

So the question is how do I make `find` execute a shell using `exec bash -c` on a bunch of find results and exit at the first one that fails **and** also return a non-zero exit code that I can inspect later in my script?

*** actual script ***

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
find path-a path-b path-c \
  -iname build.xml -not -exec bash -c 'echo -n "building {} ..." && ant -f {} build && echo "success" || (echo "failure" && exit 1)' \; -quit
RESULT=$?
echo "result was $RESULT"
```

Comment: I think `find` is not suitable for this. You can `kill $PPID` in the subshell, but i don't know how to do the return thing. Maybe you can combine `find` with some `bash` code, like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would sort of do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=0
while IFS= read -r -u3 -d $'\0' file; do
        echo -n "building $file ..."
        ant -f "$file" build &&
           echo "success" ||
           { echo "failure" ; RESULT=1 ; break; }
done 3< <(find path-a path-b path-c  -print0)

echo "result was $RESULT"
```

Note that it mixes `find` with a `bash` loop as showed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116992/capturing-output-of-find-print0-into-a-bash-array).

It does not use `$?` but instead it directly uses the variable `$RESULT`.

If everything goes fine `$RESULT` is 0, else it is 1. The loop breaks as soon as an error is encountered.

It should be hopefully safe against malicious file names (because of the use of `-print0`).

Answer (score 0):

If you are the find command, you have a difficult job to do when setting your exit code. That's because you have 2 types inputs (forgetting options for the moment) with two types of jobs:

1. The path(s) to the files you want to find. You likely would not, for example, want to exit with an error if you did `find /mnt/log/storage/place -type f -mtime +7 -print`. Likely there ARE files in your log storage which are younger than 7 days, so it is not an error to skip past them- that is your intent. It WOULD be an error if you could not get into the path `/mnt/log/storage/place` at all.
2. The expression which controls find's actions. Elements in the expression are either true or false. For the purposes of `-exec`, it is true if the command it's running returns 0, false if it returns nonzero. To change the behavior of `-exec` would render it unique among all the other expression elements in find, and likely break a lot of existing scripts out there in the world.

So, to another solution to your question: you could do something which is similar to LatinSuD's `while` loop- in that you check on your command's status from a variable- but much simpler:

```
errorout=$(find /tmp -type f \( -exec bash -c '/tmp/doit 1>/tmp/stdoutfile' \; -o -quit \) 2>&1 )
```

If the script `/tmp/doit` is not executable or produces output to stderr, the errorout variable will get filled. Test errorout and react like:

```
[ -n "$errorout" ] || { echo 'Oh no- an error from find!'; /do/something/else; }
```

For a one-liner, you could do this:

```
errorout=$(find /tmp -type f \( -exec bash -c '/bin/false || { echo "error" 1>&2; exit 1; }' \; -o -quit \) 2>&1 )
```

Replace `/bin/false` with a command of your choosing. You can execute a command list like this:

```
errorout=$(find /tmp -type f \( -exec bash -c '{ command1 && command2 && command3; } || { echo "error" 1>&2; exit 1; }' \; -o -quit \) 2>&1 )
```

And if you didn't want to exit immediately upon the first failure of a command in your list:

```
errorout=$(find /tmp -type f \( -exec bash -c '{ command1; command2; command3; } || { echo "error" 1>&2; exit 1; }' \; -o -quit \) 2>&1 )
```

...don't forget the semicolons before the closing braces in the command strings.